# Como posso fazer um switch rodar em paralelo com outro?

Tags: c, multithreading, switch

Fiz esse código para movimentação de um caractere para um trabalho da faculdade,porém gostaria que quando eu apertasse o 'a', eu ainda pudesse andar e a nave não fosse apagada, assim como pudesse apertar o 'a' várias vezes e sair diversos tiros,dei uma olhada na pthread mas n sei como aplicar nesse caso, se souber de outra maneira também ajudaria bastante. Não sei se pthread é a mais indicada, já que uso windows.

```
struct posicao nave_pos = {0,37,'A'};
struct posicao laser_pos = {0,36,'^'};
 void movimentacao_nave()
{
nave_pos.x = 40;
nave_pos.y = 37;
char C;

do
{
    gotoxy(nave_pos.x,nave_pos.y);
    printf("%c", nave_pos.c);
    C=getch();
    system("cls");
    switch(C)
    {
    case 75:
        nave_pos.x=nave_pos.x-1;
        if(nave_pos.x==0)
            nave_pos.x=nave_pos.x+1;
        break;
    case 77:
        nave_pos.x=nave_pos.x+1;
        if(nave_pos.x>83)
            nave_pos.x=nave_pos.x-1;
        break;
    case 'a':
            laser_pos.x = nave_pos.x;
for(laser_pos.y = 37 ; laser_pos.y > 0 ; laser_pos.y--)
{
    gotoxy(laser_pos.x,laser_pos.y);
    printf("%c", laser_pos.c);
    Sleep(50);
    system("cls");
}
        break;
    }

}
while(1);
 }
```

Comment: Tem vários pontos na sua pergunta, vou tentar ajudar: **1.** Não é possível ler mais de uma tecla usando a função `getch`, você terá que usar uma biblioteca mais avançada para isso. **2.** quanto a limpar a tela, basta remover o comando `system("cls")`, mas você terá que "apagar" tudo antes de mudar a posição e desenhar novamente. **3.** para múltiplos disparos, você precisa usar um array para guardar as posições de vários itens, e seguir o mesmo processo, apagar cada um, mudar a posição e desenhar novamente.

Comment: E tem outro ponto: você está implementando um motor de jogo de ação. Como jogo de ação, o tempo é uma mecânica importante. Assim, você não pode ir até a posição final do laser para, só então, liberar novamente a leitura. O correto seria processar cada "mudança de frame", plotar essas mudanças de frame na tela, e então tentar detectar input do usuário novamente. Você precisaria implementar algo que lembre [este código em Python](https://github.com/jeffque/gravity-system/blob/master/engine.py#L102..L162), precisaria implementar um "motor de jogo" (_game engine_)

Comment: @RicardoPontual fiz a alteração para um array, mas ainda assim não consigo , acredito que por n conseguir rodar a função varias vezes em sequencia, lendo que teclei o a varias vezes, vc saberia me informar como posso ler varias vezes?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, irei tentar implementar isto.

Comment: Já pensou em usar GOTO com outro switch em paralelo? (é pouco usual mas acho que resolveria seu problema)